# How do I simply forward email to an external address using Postfix aliases?

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

I don't want to deal with postfix virtual.

I want to use aliases (/etc/aliases)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aliases are only available for local users. You could use relayhost_maps if you want to send them through a specific server. Other than that you need to go with virtual.